# How does one convert a CodePen to PhoneGap app?

Tags: cordova

I have a CodePen project I'd like to turn into an app, but I don't know how to make my code run on PhoneGap. I click on "create a new project" and enter the name, where it's stored and everything, and then it's created. There's no place for me to enter code or anything. Can someone explain how it works to me?

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap is built on top of cordova, so both are kinda the same.

The simple answer is: in your project folder, find the www directory. You have index.html which will be rendered every time the app is opened. 
That's where you put the HTML and import links for your js/css. You're supposed to put the js/css into the www directory as well.

That's about it.

To preview your app - navigate to the folder and enter
`cordova serve`

Another way is by installing phonegap CLI `npm install phonegap -g` and then running `phonegap serve` in your project.

The docs explain everything in detail: 
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/dev/guide/cli/index.html